# Store data on device on application install without opening app

Tags: java, android, ios

Is it possible to save data to a device upon the installation of my application prior to the opening of the application?
If not, I'm looking for a way I can somehow mark a mobile device as "test device" without my application ever being opened on it (only installed).

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: In more detail, I have a lot of mobile devices, both IOS and Android and I'm going to ship them with my application installed on them, what I need is a way to tell the difference between those users and other users that have my app - the only problem is I cant guarantee that users wont have the application closed and only open it after I upload a version update and then the different data I wanted to add to those devices to mark them will be overridden by the updated version...  hence the need for an application install data addition.

Comment: "Is it possible to save data to a device upon the installation of my application prior to the opening of the application?" -- no, other than whatever is embedded in the APK itself (e.g., assets). "I'm going to ship them with my application installed on them" -- copy a file to the devices as part of installing your app on them.

Comment: how would I go about accessing that file through the application though? lets assume I install the apk and another data file on the phone how can I access it to check that file's content/existence from my application later on? is it possible to add that file directly into the application's data storage manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish between the shipped devices and every other device, use the build variants. You can add a variable to the BuildConfig class in gradle and specify a value for this sort of "prerelease" you are making and other for the build you are shipping to the store. Then, in the relevant code, check the value of the variable you created in BuildConfig.

Comment: I don't think that will help me as the devices on which I made the special build variant can download an update from the store when I release a version later on and only then open the app, that new version update will no longer have the build variant I require because it will be overridden by the update version which means I lost track of the device, am I correct?

Comment: That's true, but in that case, you can export the BuildConfig value to the Device's storage and subsequently read it from there. That way the value would be always the same, even between updates.

Comment: But that just puts me back where I started because you cant export (as far as I know) the data, or the build config values, during the application installation, and since there is the possibility that the application will not be opened prior to an application update I still don't have a resolution to the issue...

Comment: You stated previously "I have a lot of mobile devices, both IOS and Android and I'm going to ship them with my application installed on them, what I need is a way to tell the difference between those users and other users that have my app". I assumed you could open the app at least once since the devices are in your hands. To clarifiy, ¿Do you have the devices? ¿Are they going to reset them (google/ios accounts)?

Comment: I might have expressed myself incorrectly, I have a company that is distributing the devices with my app on them but I'm unable to actually manually go over all applications and open them, if I could do that I'd just save some data for that version on the app startup - thats why I was looking for a way to do this on the installation process rather than on the application startup